# Query to analyze log-in data and intelligently identify a shift worked

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a large Vertica table that tracks almost any user activity within an enterprise wide program. There is a subset of users where I want to identify the hours they worked on a day to day basis. The tricky part is that some users work 12 hour shifts that span multiple days. Could anyone suggest the best way to do this? Here's what I was originally thinking:

```
select users.max_hour - users.min_hour as shift_length, 
       timestamp_trunc(activity_dt_tm ,'ddd')
       (select username, 
               ceil(max(hour(activity_dt_tm))) as max_hour, 
               floor(min(hour(activity_dt_tm))) as min_hour
          from user_activity 
          where timestamp_trunc(activity_dt_tm ,'ddd') = '2014/11/10'
          group by username
       ) users
```

I would look at the results from that query and see which users shifts were under a minimum threshold of say 8 hours, indicating they probably started working in the afternoon into the following day. Once I have that list of usernames, I would pass them into a second query that would look ahead to the next day and grab the maximum hour of the activity data row and substitute it in for their 'max_time'. I'm not a sql expert, but I think this might involve some temporary tables to pass the data around. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

---

Edit

Here's a SQL Fiddle with some staged data for 2 users. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ce900

User2 has activity of a normal 8-5 workday. User1 starts working around 7PM and works into the next day. I'd want the output to look something like this:

```
UserName | Shift Start | Shift End | Hours Worked
-------------------------------------------------
User1    | 7PM         | 7AM       | 12
User2    | 8AM         | 5PM       | 9
```

I'd want to attribute all the hours worked to the day the user started their shift.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data set and how you want that result set to look ? Seems like you can get your result using some analytic functions. But we need the sample data & desired result. You can use SQLFiddle to prepare this (use any platform).

Comment: @Kermit didn't even know that existed. Pretty cool, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL below to find the start, end and duration of breaks that a user had. You can then filter the breaks that are longer than a threshold and use them to separate user's shifts.

```
select t1.username, t1.end_dt_tm beforeBreak, t2.start_dt_tm afterBreak, t2.start_dt_tm - t1.end_dt_tm as diff 
from user_activity t1, user_activity t2
where t1.username = t2.username and t2.start_dt_tm = 
(
  select min(nxt.start_dt_tm) from user_activity nxt 
  where nxt.username = t1.username and nxt.start_dt_tm > t1.end_dt_tm
)
;
```

(note that your fiddle has the same row twice for user 1)

Comment: Thanks, ended up going down this route examining the breaks in between activity.